# Looking for undergraduate math forum.

Tags: discussion

Hi: I have searched in google looking for math forums but, really, I have not found many. Could somebody give me the URL of a good mathematics forum for the undergraduate level? This forum I like it very much but it is always convenient to have another one at hand, I think. Thanks in advance.

P.S.: there was planetmath which was very good but now it has converted into a site for professionals.

Comment: Maybe this could help: [Useful mathematical fora](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/95787).

Comment: mersenneforum ?

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/  There are forums for various levels ... secondary, undergraduate, ...